# How to generate a dot graph with gvterm

Tags: prolog, graphviz, swi-prolog

I'm trying to use [gvterm](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=gvterm) to generate a dot graph. However, as the documention is not complete, the usage is unclear. In particular, what graph representation does gvterm expect as input?

As an example, how do I generate the following dot graph with gvterm?

```
digraph gvterm {                                                                
 a [label="This is node A"];                                                    
 a -> b [label="edge\na->b"];                                                   
 a -> c;                                                                        
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you create the code or add a package for this use case, please add a comment with my tag, I would be interested in what you find/learn/publish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [gvterm](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=gvterm) is used to `Show Prolog terms using graphviz` and a comment in the source code file `gvterm.pl` reads:

> This library translates complex Prolog terms into Graphviz (dot)
>   output for graphical rendering.

Contrary to what one would believe [gvterm](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=gvterm) is not used to create user defined graphs, but only creates graphs for existing Prolog terms.

In short I believe that Jan created the package for doing documentation of Prolog terms and nothing more.

Comment: I find the wording misleading, because "complex Prolog terms" may very well be some representations of graphs. What else than a term would the input be. But I guess you're right.

Comment: Thanks for the accept vote. I know it is not what you wanted, but it does bring closure to the search path. As I noted, I will be needing something similar to what you needed in a few weeks at the rate I am progressing and will make the code public, probably GitHub. It won't be for the full dot grammar, but enough to create AST diagrams for parsed expressions. If dot becomes a problem then I will just move to doing SVG from the input, but still plan to use Prolog to do the rewrites.